# In VHDL ..... how to count leading zeros of vector?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm working in a VHDL project and I'm facing a problem to calculate the length of vector. I know there is length attribute of a vector but this not the length I'm looking for. For example, I have `std_logic_vector`

```
    E : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

then

```
    E <= "00011010";
```

so, `len = E'length = 8` but I'm not looking for this. I want to calculate `len` after discarding the left most zeros , so `len = 5;`

I know that I can use for loop by checking "0"s bits from left to right and stop if "1" bit occur. But that's not efficient, because I have 1024 or more of bits and that will slow my circuit. So is there is any method or algorithm to calculate the length in efficient way? Such as using combinational gates of log(n) level of gates, ( where n = number of bits ).

Comment: Have you tried the naive approach?  Synthesizers can be remarkably clever at rearranging your logic.
Otherwise, ["Hackers Delight"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VicPJYM0I5QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=hackers+delight&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PwqRUYadBYHeOsH9gIgL&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA) has a number of options on pp77-80, which may be amenable to synthesis.  They shouldn't take long to code up and try - report back in an answer to this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you do with your "bit counting" very similar to the logarithm (base 2).

This is commonly used in VHDL to figure out how many bits are required to represent a signal. For example if you want to store up to N elements in RAM, the number of bits required for addressing that RAM is ceil(log2(N)). For this I use:

```
function log2ceil(m:natural) return natural is
begin -- note: for log(0) we return 0
    for n in 0 to integer'high loop
        if 2**n >= m then
            return n;
        end if;
    end loop;
end function log2ceil;
```

Usually, you want to do this at synthesis time with constants, and speed is no concern. But you can also generate FPGA logic, if that's really what you want.

As others have mentioned, a "for" loop in VHDL is just used to generate a lookup table, which may be slow due to long signal paths, but still only takes a single clock. What can happen is that your maximum clock frequency goes down. Usually this is only a problem if you operate on vectors larger than 64bit (you mentioned 1024 bits) and clocks faster than 100MHz. Maybe the synthesizer already told you that this is your problem, otherwise I suggest you try first.

Then you have to split up the operation over multiple clocks, and store some intermediate result into a FF. (I would upfront forget about trying to outsmart the synthesizer by rearranging your code. A lookup-table is a table. Why should it matter how you generate the values in this table? But make sure you tell the synthesizer about "don't care" values if you have them.)

If speed is your concern, use the first clock to check all 16bit blocks in parallel (independent of each other), and then use a second clock cycle to combine the results of all 16bit blocks into a single result. If the amount of FPGA logic is your concern, implement a state machine that checks a single 16bit block at every clock cycle.

But be careful that you don't re-invent the CPU while doing that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using a loop is that when you synthesize you might get a very long chain of logic.

Another way to look at your problem is to find the index of the most significant set bit.
To do this you can use a priority encoder. The nice thing about this is you can make a large priority encoder by using smaller priority encoders in a tree structure, so the delay is O(log N) instead of O(N).

Here is a 4 bit priority encoder:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/VHDL_for_FPGA_Design/Priority_Encoder
You can make a 16 bit priority encoder using 5 of these blocks, then a 256 bit encoder from five 16 bit encoders, etc.

But since you have so many bits it is going to be fairly huge.

Answer (score 2):

Well, VHDL is not SW, it does not take time to perform an operation like this, it just takes resources from your FPGA.

You can divide your 1024 bits data into 32 bits section and perform an OR between all the bits, this way, you check 32 bits at a time. It is not really necessary since the the for loop would work perfectly fine for what you want to do, just write the code, look for the first 1 in the array and stop the loop and use the loop index number as the pointer to the first 1 in your array. I didn't compile this code, but something like this should work for you:

```
FirstOne <= 1023;
for i in E'reverse_range loop
  if (E(i) == '1') then
    FirstOne <= i;
    exit;
  end if;
end loop;
```

It will not be such a big blocks inside an FPGA after all.

Answer (score 1):

Most synthesizers these days support recursive functions.  And indeed this will give you complexity comparable to `log(N)` where N is the number of bits:

- Cut your vector into halves
- If the top half are all zeros

  - The leading bit of your answer is '1', low bits depend on the bottom half vector
- Otherwise

  - The leading bit of your answer is '0', low bits depend on the top half vector
- Recurse on the half vector of interest chosen above