# VHDL 2008 calculate length of vector without leading zeros

Tags: vhdl

i'm writing a small vhdl module, but i'm quite new to this language.
The length of the output vector of my entity is variable, depending on the msb of my polynom. For example if i have a polynom like *100111*, *len* should be 4. So the output vector has 5 bits. 
One less than the input vector.

For clarification:
If the inputvector looks like "000100111", the output vector should also be (4 downto 0). That's why i just can't use *'length*.

```
entity CRC_n_par is
generic(
    polynom     : std_logic_vector
    );
port(
    clk     : in    std_logic;
    input   : in    std_logic;
    reset   : in    std_logic;
    output  : out   std_logic_vector(integer(ceil(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(polynom))))))-2 downto 0) );
end entity;
architecture Behavioral of CRC_n_par is

    constant len : integer := integer(ceil(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(polynom))))))-2;
```

Is there any way, to do this more elegant. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521943/in-vhdl-how-to-count-leading-zeros-of-vector) a similar question, but i cannot use a function in the port declaration. After the port declaration, i use the constant len again. 
Is there a way to use a c-like macro in vhdl? 
I'm using vhdl 2008, that's why the conversion is so complicated, because i can only convert between closely related types.

Comment: Your two declarations involve globally static values meaning the calculations are done at elaboration of the design hierarchy. Why not make constant len a generic? Calculate only once in the generic interface and use len for the port array bound. You could also hide the len calculation in a function call, the function declared in a convenient package just like ceil or log2.

Comment: I wanted to give only one generic value, so the upper hierarchy don't have to calculate the lenght, which can cause errors. Or do you mean to define the constant just below the polynom generic? GHDL throws me an error, "polynom" is not visible here

Comment: The algorithm to get from `polynom` to `len` is still not clear. Could you describe that more specifically?

Comment: Use ghdl's -08 flag  (ghdl -a --std=08 crc_par_n.vhdl) to make polynom visible in generic. It's a -2008 feature and required to be used where elaboration occurs (commands -e  for gcc/llvm or -r for mcode) . You could also pass len as a natural and do the calculation where crc_n_par is instantiated which will work -1993 and later. Ask your self how the place instantiating crc_n_par knows the length of the output port, needed to declare an actual signal, used during elaboration associating an actual signal and formal port.

Comment: @JHBonarius 
The log2 needs an real input, thats why i cast the polynom to unsigned and after that to real. log2(0b000100111) = 5,28, ceil increases to 6 (bits)
My output length should be 1 less, so 5 bit. When defining a vector range, i have to specify (4 downto 0)

Comment: Ah, so you want to say the output has five *bits*, not bytes. But I still don't see what it has to do with the msb(most significant bit) of the polynome.

Comment: Sorry, just corrected bytes to bits, awful fault of mine. It should be the first '1' in the vector, technically it's not the msb, you're right.

Comment: I think a loop counting zeroes from the high bit down would be more elegant than that mess ... hide it in a function. As it's a generic not a port, it'll be evaluated at elaboration time, costing no hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length is also needed were crc_n_par is instantiated:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity crc_n_par is
    generic (
        len:           natural
    );
    port (
        clk:      in    std_logic;
        input:    in    std_logic;
        reset:    in    std_logic;
        output:   out   std_logic_vector (len - 1 downto 0) 
    );
end entity;
architecture Behavioral of crc_n_par is
begin
MONITOR:
    process
    begin
        report "crc_n_par output len = " & integer'image(len);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity some_top_level is
end entity;

architecture foo of some_top_level is
    -- For -2002 and earlier, present in -2008:
    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;
    constant polynom: std_logic_vector := "000100111";
    constant crc_inst_len : natural := 
        integer(ceil(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(polynom))))))-1;
    signal clk:     std_logic;
    signal input:   std_logic;
    signal reset:   std_logic;
    signal output:  std_logic_vector (crc_inst_len - 1 downto 0);
begin
MONITOR:
    process
    begin
        report LF & "polynom len = " & integer'image(polynom'length) &
               " crc_inst_len = " & integer'image(crc_inst_len) & LF &
               " output length = " & integer'image(output'length) & 
               " polynom = " & to_string(polynom);
        wait;
    end process;
CRC_INSTANCE:
    entity work.crc_n_par 
        generic map (
            len => crc_inst_len
        )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            input => input,
            reset => reset,
            output => output
        );

end architecture;
```

This moves the length calculation to a higher point in the design hierarchy allowing the actual used for the port output to be declared with the proper length as well.

When analyzed, elaborated and simulated it produces:

> ```
> ghdl -a some_top_level.vhdl
> ghdl -e some_top_level
> ghdl -r some_top_level
> some_top_level.vhdl:20:9:@0ms:(report note): crc_n_par output len = 5
> some_top_level.vhdl:55:9:@0ms:(report note):
> polynom len = 9 crc_inst_len = 5
>  output length = 5 polynom = 000100111
> ```

You can independently calculate the length two places:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity crc_n_par is
    generic (
        polynom:       std_logic_vector;
        len:           natural :=  -- requires -2008 to access polynom
            integer(ceil(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(polynom)))))) - 1
        );
    port (
        clk:      in    std_logic;
        input:    in    std_logic;
        reset:    in    std_logic;
        output:   out   std_logic_vector (len - 1 downto 0) 
    );
end entity;
architecture Behavioral of crc_n_par is
begin
MONITOR:
    process
    begin
        report "len = " & integer'image(len);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity some_top_level is
end entity;

architecture foo of some_top_level is
    constant polynom: std_logic_vector := "000100111";
    constant crc_inst_len : natural := 
        integer(ceil(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(polynom))))))-1;
    signal clk:     std_logic;
    signal input:   std_logic;
    signal reset:   std_logic;
    signal output:  std_logic_vector (crc_inst_len - 1 downto 0);
begin
MONITOR:
    process
    begin
        report LF & "polynom len = " & integer'image(polynom'length) &
               " crc_inst_len = " & integer'image(crc_inst_len) & LF &
               " output length = " & integer'image(output'length) & 
               " polynom = " & to_string(polynom);
        wait;
    end process;
CRC_INSTANCE:
    entity work.crc_n_par 
        generic map (
            polynom => polynom
            -- don't pass len
        )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            input => input,
            reset => reset,
            output => output
        );
end architecture;
```

But you can see that's unnecessary duplication and requires -2008 to analyze and elaborate:

> ```
> ghdl -a --std=08 crc_n_par.vhdl
> ghdl -e --std=08 crc_n_par
> ghdl -r --std=08 some_top_level
> some_top_level.vhdl:20:9:@0ms:(report note): crc_n_par output len = 5
> some_top_level.vhdl:55:9:@0ms:(report note):
> polynom len = 9 crc_inst_len = 5
>  output length = 5 polynom = 000100111
> ```

Note the `- 1` in calculating `polynom` length matches your question title:

**VHDL 2008 calculate length of vector without leading zeros**

And this is the purpose of using conversion of the array value to an integer and determining it's log2 ceiling and subtracting one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my ghdl throws an error("polynom is not visible here") even when using --std=08. What Version to you use? I have ghdl-0.33

I want to use --std=08 as default, because it's a new project, we don't have to maintenaince older parts. Or is there anything bad with vhdl2008 in your opinion?
However, i think, it's the best to give the length as a generic constant, because i'll ned it in higher hierarchy levels, as you mentioned.

Comment: In your first example, `polynom` is not included as a generic. I'm assuming the asker wants to be able to change it of each instantiation (else it would not bea generic, but instead just a constant within the architecture). And in the comments the asker specifically request that he only wants to gives one generic value...

Comment: generics can propagate down through an architecture. Where does polynom come from?

Answer (score 0):

First off: your question is unclear. You say you want to determine the length of a vector without leading zeroes. `100111` has no leading zeros, so the length is 6. And it is also not clear how you go from a length of 4 to 5 bytes.

Well, it depends on your specific implementation what would be an optimal approach. I would use a function in a package. I.e.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package my_functions is
    function det_output_len(polynom:std_logic_vector) return positive;
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

package body my_functions is
    function det_output_len(polynom:std_logic_vector) return positive is
    begin
        return integer(ceil(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(polynom))))))-1;
    end function;
end package body;
```

Then in your entity:

```
use work.my_functions.all;

entity CRC_n_par is
    [...]
port(
    [...]
    output  : out   std_logic_vector(det_output_len(polynom)-1 downto 0) );
end entity;
```

As for constant 'len', you don't need to recalculate the function. If the length has already been set for the output vector, you can just get is using [VHDL attributes](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html) (old site, not up-to-date on VHDL-2008). I.e.

```
constant len : positive := output'length;
```

By the way, this is not a VHDL-2008 specific thing, as it is supported in VHDL for some time.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. If i use my formula on "100111", the result is 4. (Check the -2 at the ending). And the same result should be for "000100111".

Comment: So how does the architecture instantiating crc_n_par in the design hierarchy know to declare an actual signal of the correct length to associate with port output?

Comment: @user1155120 that architecture, which also sets the polynome, would also have to call the function to determine the length. I will add that to the answer when I gave more time. Like I say in the answer: this is just a possible solution. It all depends on your choice of implementation.