# Is there any short-way to find first '1' bit?

Tags: bit-manipulation, vhdl, fpga

I want to show ,the mentioned problem on the title, to you in a function.

```
finding_first_one(signal a : std_logic_vector(...)) { return bit_number }
```

Meaning this, lets say, we have a signal '10010100', then return value, bit_number, should be 2. Is there any short way to find it in one cycle. I do not want to scan all the bits per clock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In VHDL … how to count leading zeros of vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16521943/995714), just reverse the bits and work like in the other question. Or you can use a lookup table. A 4-bit LUT will help you skip 4 bits at a time

Comment: related: [find the first bit equal to zero, and set it to one](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/hdl-problem-first-bit-equal-to-zero-and-set-it-to-one/)

Comment: thanks. I guess, they are all did with for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a for loop in your function.
Be aware that for loop cannot always be implemented on hardware and that it can use **A LOT** of logic elements.
Try something like this (not tested). `index` should be equal to 2 in one clock cycle.

```
architecture behav of test is

  signal sig    : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := x"2224";
  signal index  : integer;

  function finding_first_one (signal a : std_logic_vector()) return integer is
  begin    
    for i in a'low to a'high loop
      if a(i) = '1' then
        return i;
      end if;
    end loop;    
    -- all zero
    return -1;
  end function;

begin

  process (CLK)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      index <= finding_first_one(sig);
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: you are most probably right, I cant see any other way except yours.