# VHDL: (Data Flow and Control Unit) calculate log2, represented as an unsigned 8-bit integer

Tags: vhdl, shift-register

I need to design a digital circuit, in the form of Data Flow and Control, to calculate the entire portion of the logarithm at base 2 of a positive number N, represented as an unsigned 8-bit integer in VHDL.

Basically I'll do this:

```cpp
int log2 (int N) {

    int count = -1;
    while (N>0){
        N = N >> 1;
        count++
    }
    return count;
}
```

I'll use 8-bit integer to represent the number N and dislocate with 0's to the right. Then, the number of dislocation minus 1, is equal to the log2.

I have already made the entity:

```vhdl
entity log2 is

    port (
        clock, reset: in bit; -- global control: clock and reset
        start: in bit;
        ready: out bit; -- finished execution (equal to 1 when the calculation is finished)
        N: in bit_vector(7 downto 0);
        logval: out bit_vetor(3 downto 0) -- log2(N)
        );
end entity log2;
```

But I'm struggling with the following process.

I've made a ASM diagram to help, and there it is:

[image: Flow chart of design]

And I also know that I need some data flow elements like:

- for the "reg" i'll need a shift register,
- for the log i'll need a counter register

I've only been able to see this at theory, i'm struggling to put all of this into code.

Does anybody know how can I start the architecture?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. You can create a simple FSM for this, but that will lead to a rather poor performance.

Comment: What you are actually trying to find here can be achieved with a leading-zero-counter:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521943/in-vhdl-how-to-count-leading-zeros-of-vector
So Log2(N) = BitsWidthOf(N) - LZC(N)

Comment: If you need a sequential implementation, the calculation can be done in LogN steps.
Pay attention that your drawing is flow diagram. It's great for software. For cycle-accurate hardware description- less. Try to draw an FSM diagram for a simple case of a small 4 bit number and draw inspiration from that.